# How to hide a div on a button click using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation to validate the sign up form. Everything is working. But there is a message in span below the input type password with id **password_msg**. This message shows before the submit form.
Now same message also in validation message for password. When I click on submit, then both message is showing. I need when I click on submit, then the message, which is below the password tag in span with id **password_msg** should be hide. Only validation message should be show.

```
<input name="password" class="form-control" type="password" id="password" placeholder="************">
  <span class="font-13 text-danger" id="password_msg">
    Password should be a minimum of 8 characters including uppercase and lowercase letters, at least 1 number and at least 1 special character (!@#$%^&*).
  </span>
 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-5 col-xs-6 text-left">
   <button type="submit" class="next_button" name="reg_user">Sign up</button>
 </div>
```

My jquery is:

```
$('form[id="validate_form"]').validate({
rules: {
  password: {
        required: true,
            }
 },
messages: {
   ,
    password: {
      required: 'Password should be a minimum of 8 characters including uppercase and lowercase letters, at least 1 number and at least 1 special character (!@#$%^&*).',
               }
 },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

I tried to hide the message:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#reg_user').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#password_msg').hide();
});
});
```

But both message appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand your question but the fix can be the below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.next_button').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#password_msg').hide();
});
})
```